# dying processes (going defunct)

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a script that is using several ssh sessions to upload files to remote hosts. It has been working for years. For some reason recently it stopped working, because 2 of the processes die (they go defunct).

How to find out why are they dying?

Below is output from ps

```
root@vm-img1-en:~# ps aux | grep ssh | grep root
root      2389  0.0  0.1   4648  1048 ?        Ss   01:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      2517  0.0  0.3   7576  2464 ?        Ss   01:01   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root      2563  0.0  0.3   7576  2460 ?        Ss   01:01   0:00 sshd: root@pts/1
root      2873  0.0  0.5   8820  3828 ?        Ss   01:07   0:01 sshd: root@pts/2
root      3702  0.0  0.3   4668  2048 pts/1    S+   01:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -T -l rdamuq -p 22 vm-ss3.ba.nc
root      3713  0.1  0.7   7504  4904 pts/1    S+   01:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -T -l rdamuq -p 22 vm-ss1.fl.nc
root      3716  0.0  0.2   4648  1992 pts/1    S+   01:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -T -l rdamuq -p 22 vm-ss1.ba.nc
root      3717  0.0  0.2   4532  1984 pts/1    S+   01:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -T -l rdamuq -p 22 vm-img1-skbg.sf.nc
root      3728  0.0  0.2   4532  1984 pts/1    S+   01:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -T -l rdamuq -p 22 vm-img1.ow.nc
root      3733  0.0  0.2   4652  1992 pts/1    S+   01:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -T -l rdamuq -p 22 vm-ss2.ba.nc
root      3744  0.0  0.2   4536  1984 pts/1    S+   01:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -T -l rdamuq -p 22 vm-ss1.fr.nc
root      3749  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   01:23   0:00 [ssh] <defunct>
root      3750  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   01:23   0:00 [ssh] <defunct>
root      3751  0.0  0.2   4532  1984 pts/1    S+   01:23   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -T -l rdamuq -p 22 vm-img1.su.nc
```

Comment: I notice that all the surviving `ssh` processes are to different hosts.  What hosts were the two defunct ones to?  Is there any chance they're just dying of natural causes, and going zombie because their parent's no longer around?

Comment: run them under the script command, each to a different file, to see what is happening

Comment: @Skaperen well the thing is I have to reverse engineer that script. I had the same idea initially.

Comment: @MadHatter I don't think this is the problem. Process that is starting all the SSH processes is up. Or you mean parent of those SSH processes that are defunct?

Comment: Not all the extant `ssh -o Strict...` processes have the same PPID, so yes, I meant the PPID of the zombies.